# Object.height returns half height

Tags: javascript, html, height

I have a canvas which height i am trying to get via JavaScript but it returns half height then the actual height

Here is the simple code i am using

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = canvas.height;
console.log(canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas#clock{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border:#D50003 1px solid;
 background:#1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock"></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: You are not setting height to the `canvas` anywhere hence default height which is **150px** is returned. The default size of **300x150**. For canvas, you need to set size either using inline `width/height` attribute or using javascript like `canvas.width=300`

Comment: i have set height to 300px in css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canvas's width and height are not set by CSS, they're set by the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas. You're seeing 150 because that's the default height. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height):

> The HTMLCanvasElement.height property is a positive integer reflecting the height HTML attribute of the  element interpreted in CSS pixels. When the attribute is not specified, or if it is set to an invalid value, like a negative, the default value of 150 is used.

The CSS width and height define the *layout space* occupied by the canvas. If they don't match the canvas size, the canvas is **scaled** to fill the layout space. E.g., what you're doing in your code is taking a 300x150 canvas (default dimensions) and stretching it to fill a 300x300 area.

While you *can* get the height applied by the CSS by using `getComputedStyle`:

```
var height = getComputedStyle(canvas).height; // "300px"
```

...that's not the height of the *canvas*, that's the height it's occupying in your layout.

If you set the width and height on the canvas, you'll get back those values (and if they match the CSS, and your drawing won't be stretched/compressed):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = canvas.height;
console.log(canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas#clock{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border:#D50003 1px solid;
 background:#1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Let's prove that the canvas in your original code is actually 300x150 being stretched to 300x300 by drawing a circle on it:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = canvas.height;
console.log(canvas.height);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var path = new Path2D();
path.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill(path);
```

```css
canvas#clock {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: #D50003 1px solid;
  background: #1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock"></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

As you can see, the circle is distorted because we're using the default size of the canvas, 300x150, but stretching it to 300x300. If we specify the size, it's correct:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = canvas.height;
console.log(canvas.height);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var path = new Path2D();
path.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill(path);
```

```css
canvas#clock {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: #D50003 1px solid;
  background: #1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: can i get height value from any method if i apply height with css